# lxc-create --download gives different list as root

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, sudo, lxc, linux-containers

My system: **Ubuntu 14.04.2 amd64**

See this:

```
$ lxc-create --template download --name mycontainer
Setting up the GPG keyring
Downloading the image index

---
DIST    RELEASE ARCH    VARIANT BUILD
---
centos  6   amd64   default 20150415_02:16
centos  6   i386    default 20150415_02:16
debian  wheezy  amd64   default 20150414_22:42
debian  wheezy  armel   default 20150412_22:42
debian  wheezy  armhf   default 20150414_22:42
debian  wheezy  i386    default 20150414_22:42
gentoo  current amd64   default 20150414_14:12
gentoo  current armhf   default 20150414_14:12
gentoo  current i386    default 20150414_14:12
oracle  6.5 amd64   default 20150415_11:40
oracle  6.5 i386    default 20150415_11:40
plamo   5.x amd64   default 20150414_21:36
plamo   5.x i386    default 20150414_21:36
ubuntu  precise amd64   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  precise armel   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  precise armhf   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  precise i386    default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  trusty  amd64   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  trusty  armhf   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  trusty  i386    default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  trusty  ppc64el default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  utopic  amd64   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  utopic  armhf   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  utopic  i386    default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  utopic  ppc64el default 20150415_03:49
---
```

Now, the same command, but with sudo:

```
$ sudo lxc-create --template download --name mycontainer
[sudo] password for user: 
Setting up the GPG keyring
Downloading the image index

---
DIST    RELEASE ARCH    VARIANT BUILD
---
centos  6   amd64   default 20150415_02:16
centos  6   i386    default 20150415_02:16
centos  7   amd64   default 20150415_02:16
debian  jessie  amd64   default 20150414_22:42
debian  jessie  armel   default 20150414_22:42
debian  jessie  armhf   default 20150414_22:42
debian  jessie  i386    default 20150414_22:42
debian  sid amd64   default 20150414_22:42
debian  sid armel   default 20150412_22:42
debian  sid armhf   default 20150414_22:42
debian  sid i386    default 20150414_22:42
debian  wheezy  amd64   default 20150414_22:42
debian  wheezy  armel   default 20150412_22:42
debian  wheezy  armhf   default 20150414_22:42
debian  wheezy  i386    default 20150414_22:42
fedora  19  amd64   default 20150415_01:27
fedora  19  armhf   default 20150415_01:27
fedora  19  i386    default 20150415_01:27
fedora  20  amd64   default 20150415_01:27
fedora  20  armhf   default 20150415_01:27
fedora  20  i386    default 20150415_01:27
gentoo  current amd64   default 20150414_14:12
gentoo  current armhf   default 20150414_14:12
gentoo  current i386    default 20150414_14:12
oracle  6.5 amd64   default 20150415_11:40
oracle  6.5 i386    default 20150415_11:40
plamo   5.x amd64   default 20150414_21:36
plamo   5.x i386    default 20150414_21:36
ubuntu  precise amd64   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  precise armel   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  precise armhf   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  precise i386    default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  trusty  amd64   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  trusty  armhf   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  trusty  i386    default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  trusty  ppc64el default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  utopic  amd64   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  utopic  armhf   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  utopic  i386    default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  utopic  ppc64el default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  vivid   amd64   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  vivid   armhf   default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  vivid   i386    default 20150415_03:49
ubuntu  vivid   ppc64el default 20150415_03:49
---
```

Seems like there are some images not available to use for unprivileged containers (like `CentOS 7`). How could I use the full list of images with my own user? I don't like to use privileged containers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different lists, one for privileged containers (system) and one for unprivileged containers (user). You can see the lists here: https://images.linuxcontainers.org/meta/1.0/. I assume that the reason there are two lists is because certain containers don't work with unprivileged LXC. If that's true then it's pointless to see those containers since you can't use them.